# Lightweight tiler and management for static images

Tags: raster, layers, tiles, mosaic-dataset

This is only marginally GIS related, but I think that this community will have the most experience with tiling:

I am looking for a lightweight framework that can place a large number of high resolution images *without reprojection* on a map, and generate tiles of the result, with the aim of displaying them as leaflet tile layer. Think of a single layer zoomable gallery, or a mosaic dataset without georeferencing.

Ideally there could be a visual editor to place the boundaries, but editing a database or configuration file is ok.

Ideally I would like to skip
georeferencing and use absolute pixel coordinates at a given zoom level.

Can be a lightweight server or a static tile generator.

Which framework would you use? I'm somewhat familiar with mapserver and geoserver, and could probably work with basic raster layers in mapserver. I just wondered if there is something simpler and more interactive that I'm not aware of.

Comment: My current research led me to librasterlite2, which seems to support unreferenced images, and should be able to handle a larger number of layers. Still happy to get feedback if there is an easier way.

Comment: I still have to find a version of librasterlite2 that doesn't core dump on 90% of the tests, or when importing the source image.

Comment: Have you contacted Rasterlite developers? There is a Spatialite-users Google group for communication.